# printing problems. Light lines are almost disappeared

Tags: printing

Is it possible to obtain better printing results for the light lines of a .tiff image? 
While on the screen I can still see all the thin lines, when I print many of them turn into dashed lines. I applied also auto levels but the result didn't get better. Then I apllied ctrl+L and I positioned the value of gray from 1,00 to 0,6 but the problem persists. I don't know what else I should do.

[image]

Comment: Printer resolution and screen resolution are not the same thing.  Additionally printers rarely default to highest resolution.

Comment: Thank you, I know that it isn't the same thing, it was for making easer my problem to be understand.

Comment: People will just be guessing from your description.  Can you add an image of the print sample plus a description of the source and settings that produced it?  (Post a link to an image-sharing site like imgur.com and someone will embed it in your question for you.)

Comment: As you can notice at the photo of the print all the light lines are vanished or turned into dashed ones. I don't know how to fix it. Thank you!

Comment: I think you need a drawing program. Tools like illustrator may help to find the lines (trace) but as the lines are incomplete this may be no good. However, using a drawing program may allow you to manually complete the lines. If you draw over it on a new layer (trace) then you can remove the background as well

Comment: Thank you for your response Dave. The problem is the printing result. That above is the photo of the print. The original file is a very nitid image with some fine/light lines. When I print it the result is what I enclosed above.

Answer (score -1):

It was enough to use CURVES from IMAGE and then ADJUSTMENTS.

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what adjustments you made to the curves to rectify the issue? A screenshot of the curves profile would be helpful :)